# MySQL sort by, then sort a selection by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I extract a number of rows from my DB with a query. Let's say that the result is 120 rows. I want to order these rows by 'score'. That's easy, since every row has a field called 'score'. Next I want to order the first 20 rows of the result randomly. So: 1st order by score, then order first 20 randomly. How would I do this?

EDIT: to be clear: I want to show ALL 120 rows, just onder the first 20 of them randomly.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do it by SQL onlyof a bit of PHP is ok ?

Comment: @NMC, combination of PHP and MYSQL is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose you've got all your results in a PHP array `$rows`, using something like this SQL:

```
SELECT * from `table_name` order by `score`;
```

It sounds like you know how to do that bit, so I omit the details.  The bit you want is the following:

```
// Get the first 20 rows
$top_twenty = array_slice($rows, 0, 20)

// Order them randomly
shuffle($top_twenty);

// Put them back into the $rows array, with their new order
$rows = array_replace($rows, $top_twenty);
```

Comment: It might not be so elegant, but I actually really like your method. Especially because it doesn't increase the MYSQL load, which is already high enough as it is. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I'm happy that it helps.  Note that I've just edited my answer, to use the `array_replace` function instead of a loop.  This is just a refactoring of the code: the effect is exactly the same (apart from unused side condition of the variable $i, which has disappeared).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried shuffling the associative array obtained in the result of the SQL?

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score LIMIT 20");
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

shuffle($array);

foreach($array as $item) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is a great alternative to the rather performance-heavy RAND() function, but the above query won't show the other 100 rows if I'm correct?

Comment: @user2704687: Steps: 1. select 20 ordered. 2. shuffle. 3. select the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand that what you wanted is all together. @dvijaz's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @rowNum=0;

SELECT @rowNum:=@rowNum+1 AS rowSeq,t.*
FROM tableName t
ORDER BY case  WHEN rowSeq < 20 THEN Rand() ELSE score END
```

Comment: This answer received an upvote, not sure why, because this query  doesn't return the resultset in the order specified by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL-only (well MySQL-only) solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      FROM table cross join
           (select @rn := 0) const
      ORDER BY score
     ) t
ORDER BY (rn <= 20) desc,
         (case when rn <= 20 then rand() end),
         score;
```

Comment: hi gordon .. i have a confusion ..plz help .. does SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ..... ORDER BY col) gauranteed to give sorted resulted as specified in inner query.. ?

Comment: @m hasan: not sure if the behavior is "guaranteed", but it's observable, the rows retrieved from the inline view `t` will be "in order" according to the ORDER BY clause in the inline view query. The net effect is that the `rn` column will be returned in sequence 1,2,3. As far the outer query, the only guarantee we have is the ORDER BY on the outermost query.

Comment: @mhasan . . . The `order by` in the subquery has nothing to do with the final results.  It is merely use to set the `@rn` variable (note that I just changed the `order by` conditions to use `@rn` rather than `score`).